# Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, json, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN Stack messaging app. I am trying to retrieve a response from my backend as such but get the following error:

> "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)"

The problem in the below code is the 'json' part of res.json()

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService  {
    constructor (private httpClient : HttpClient ){}

    messages = []
    getMessage(){
        this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/posts').subscribe(res =>{
        //FIX AT LATER STAGE should be this.messages = res.json()
        this.messages = res.json();
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: HttpClient parses the result as JSON automatically. You don’t need to execute json method on the response. What happens if you log console.log(res)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the situation with Angular:

#### `HttpModule` (< Angular 4.3<sup>*</sup>)

```js
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
```

- Old and deprecated
- JSON responses need to manually parsed: `res.json()`

#### `HttpClientModule` (Angular 4.3+)

```js
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

- Current (LTS)
- JSON responses are already parsed. `res.json()` is not required.

---

<sub>* I might be a little off with the version number. Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).</sub>